# How to highlight selected panels in matplotlib? Tight layout ignored added patched

Tags: matplotlib

I want to highlight some panels of my figure, but the command `tight_layout()` will misalign the added rectangle with the aimed panel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(5, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                        gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

axs = axs.flatten() 

ax = axs[4]
chartBox = ax.get_position()
x0, y0, x1, y1, w, h = chartBox.x0, chartBox.y0, chartBox.x1, chartBox.y1, chartBox.width, chartBox.height

fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((x0, y0),
                        w, h,
                        fc ='none', 
                        transform=fig.transFigure,
                        figure=fig,
                        ec ='r',
                        lw = 4)])


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure: The added rectangle is shifted by tight_layout()]

Comment: What are you placing the box in figure coordinates if you want it to follow the axes?  Just use transAxes instead.

Comment: @JodyKlymak not really to me, can you prove that the` transAxes` will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(5, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                        gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

ax = axs[1, 1]

fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((0, 0),
                        1, 1,
                        fc ='none', 
                        transform=ax.transAxes,
                        figure=fig,
                        ec ='r',
                        lw = 4)])

plt.show()
```

Gives you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions with minimum change of the above code is to provoke `tight_layout()` earlier than plotting the patch.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(5, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                        gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})

axs = axs.flatten() 

plt.tight_layout()

ax = axs[4]
chartBox = ax.get_position()
x0, y0, x1, y1, w, h = chartBox.x0, chartBox.y0, chartBox.x1, chartBox.y1, chartBox.width, chartBox.height

fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((x0, y0),
                        w, h,
                        fc ='none', 
                        transform=fig.transFigure,
                        figure=fig,
                        ec ='r',
                        lw = 4)])

plt.show()
```

[image]